# Selecting only row with highest number from ROW_NUM to get the latest update

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am still learning SQL.  Currently, I was able to get row number from partitioning and row_number()

However, I am stuck where I can't think of a way to select the highest row_num in order to view only the records with latest update.

I get invalid column name at the end.  I apologize for the messy structure, I plan to clean it up better.

Thank you in advance for any answers/hints from you guys.  I appreciate your time.

Edit:  The latest update is actually the highest row_num return rather than 1.  I forgot to specify.

```
FROM
        (
        SELECT
        a.DELFLAG,
        a.fname, 
        a.lname, 
        a.key1, 
        l.key2,
        l.update,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY key1, key2 ORDER BY l.lupdate DESC) AS row_num 

FROM dbo.t1 a
    
    INNER JOIN dbo.t2 i ON i.key1 = a.key1
    INNER JOIN dbo.t3 l ON l.key1 = i.key1
    ) AS K  

WHERE 
    [row_num] = SELECT MAX([row_num]) AS latest)
    AND
    DELFLAG = 0
```

Edit 2: Since a record could be updated multiple times on the same day but only the last row number reflected the latest update.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could calculate the maximum row number by just using `count()` and then using that in the `where` clause:

```
   COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY key1, key2) AS cnt
```

And then:

```
WHERE cnt = row_num
```

This assumes that you want one row per pair of `key1`/`key2`.

Comment: this ended up working out perfectly for what I needed, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is your code:

```
WHERE 
    [row_num] = SELECT MAX([row_num]) AS latest)
```

Most likely, you want:

```
WHERE 
    [row_num] = 1
```

Rationale: `row_number()` *ranks* records within partitions; in your code, it assigns rank `1` to the record with the max `l.update` for each `(key1, key2)` tuple. These are the records you want to retain, so... Just filter on `[row_num] = 1`.

On the other hand, if you want the *earliest* record per partition, then use an ascending sort in the `order by` clause of the window function rather than a descending sort:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY key1, key2 ORDER BY l.lupdate) as row_num
```

The outer query still filters on `row_num = 1`.

Comment: Whoops, I apologize for not thoroughly explain the structure.  The latest update is actually the largest row_num instead of 1.... Thank you

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation and rationale.  While it is helping me understanding further, I made an edit 2 to explain further why it wouldn't work in my case.  Hopefully, I've explained my situation thoroughly.

Comment: @SabreTheCat: which row gets the *last* row number is defined by the `order by` clause of the window functions. All you have to do is pick the sort direction (`order by l.update [asc/desc]`) that puts the interesting row first...